# Find substring of keyword using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to find out the url containing a **string/substring** in the `<td>` tag from a list of urls using BeautifulSoup. It works fine if the complete string is present but fails for a substring. This is the code I have written so far:

```
for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all("td", text=the_word)
    print(words)
    print(url)
```

I don't know much. Could anybody please direct me to search for the substrings too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [custom function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to check if the *word* is present in the text.

```
html = '''
<td>the keyword is present in the text</td>
<td>the keyword</td>
<td></td>
<td>the word is not present in the text</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
the_word = 'keyword'
tags = soup.find_all('td', text=lambda t: t and the_word in t)
print(tags)
# [<td>the keyword is present in the text</td>, <td>the keyword</td>]
```

Usually only `the_word in t` would work. But, if there are any `<td>` tags that don't have any text, as shown in the example (`<td></td>`), using `the_word in t` would raise a `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. That's why we first have to check if text is not `None`. Hence the function `lambda t: t and the_word in t`.

---

If you are not comfortable with `lambda`s, you can use a simple function which is equivalent to the one above:

```
def contains_word(t):
    return t and 'keyword' in t

tags = soup.find_all('td', text=contains_word)
```

Comment: Its brilliant! I have a small doubt. What goes in the argument `t`? Is it automatically assigned? I am not fluent with lambda expressions very much. So is it **necessary** to store the returned value of the function/lambda expression in `text` or is assigning the returned value to `text` redundant?

Comment: t is just a parameter to the function. In this case it is the text of the tag. And here, we are not assigning the function to text. Just as you were matching text using `text=thetext`, we are checking if text is equal to the conditions specified in the function. So it'll return a tag whose text matches the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this directly. The only way I can think of is to put all of the text from the 'td' tags into a data structure such as a list or dictionary and test it there.

Comment: Actually, there's a nice and simple way to achieve this. BeautifulSoup allows us to use [custom functions](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) with `find()` and `find_all()`. Have a look at the documentation link, they have good examples.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar thank you very much for that, added to my knowledge!